# What is the difference between ASUS Boot Menu items

Tags: uefi, asus

When I use F2 to enter UEFI settings after boot, the ASUS boot menu shows me a list of available boot items.

I have a USB drive inserted and I see 2 related items to it:

- Generic Flash Disk (15000MB)
- UEFI: (FAT) Generic Flash Disk (15000MB)

When I select the first one, I am able to boot using the USB drive, however when I pick the second one it does not boot into the option menu for that USB drive (the USB drive has a Fedora installation image that I created on a Mac by using the `dd` command from an ISO file).

What is the difference between these 2 items?

(Note that I am currently debugging a failed Fedora installation and picking the second item gives me the blank screen that my new Fedora install is giving me.)

Answer (score 1):

The second option includes the word UEFI, so it seems to (attempt to) boot using the new UEFI-style bootloader.

By exclusion, the first option `Generic Flash Disk (15000MB)` probably uses the legacy BIOS+MBR boot method.

Using the UEFI-style boot option on booting the installer will allow the installer to set up the new OS using UEFI-style boot also. This is the "way of the future" and in theory it is the preferable way. In practice, however, some UEFI implementations, particularly on the first systems that had UEFI firmware in place of a regular BIOS, sometimes had quite serious firmware bugs.

If your particular system has a firmware bug that causes Fedora's UEFI bootloader to fail, your options are either to see if there are firmware updates (often still called "BIOS updates" even with UEFI) available for your hardware, or using the legacy boot style for now.

Also, note that when using UEFI-style booting with an old GPU, it might need a firmware update also. If the GPU has only a legacy Video BIOS in it and not an embedded UEFI driver, the display may be blank until the OS starts up its own display drivers, unless the system BIOS is clever enough to use legacy compatibility routines (sometimes called CSM = Compatibility Support Module) with the GPU if needed even when booting UEFI-style.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with several Linux distributions and it took me some time to sort it out. The fedora wiki came in handy.

Generally, command line methods for creating a live USB stick are unsupported by fedora. Some such methods might work with UEFI but it also might not. It is explained [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/creating-and-using-a-live-installation-image/index.html) how to and how not to create such a USB stick and there is a rather lengthy discussion about UEFI [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface).